# A difficulty in understanding why there is a problem in the function constructed for Q.1.1.8(c) in Alan Pollack and Guillemin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-topology

I am asking about part(c) of this question:

[image]

The solution is given below:

[image]

[image]

But I could not understand in the solution of (c) why the implicit function $x \rightarrow r$ is not smooth at 0 and where we used this function and how tweaking the function that we constructed can solve this problem ? more clearly I could not understand the last 2 sentences in the solution of (c), could anyone explain them for me please?

Comment: I'm not sure who's responsible for these solutions. First of all, this is not an implicit function — it's an explicit function. And no, $r$ is not a smooth function of $x$ at $x=0$. But the function $h$ is already defined to be $0$ on a neighborhood of $x=0$, and a constant function is certainly smooth. Tweak? Oy. (It *is* disappointing that we're using $x$ as the variable in $\Bbb R$ and then $x$ as the (vector) variable in $\Bbb R^k$. That is not optimal.)

Comment: you mean that the function is correct and nothing wrong with it? @TedShifrin